# ¿Cómo puedo borrar los widgets creados apartir de un for (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, bucles

he estado intentando borrar unos Label y Entry que se crearon en un bucle for, sin embargo al usar `.destroy()` en el nombre de los datos pero solo borra el ultimo, por ahi estive viendo algo de "independización de los widgets" pero ni idea.

```
from tkinter import*

class principalWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        
    def borra(self):
        self.periodon.destroy()
        self.demanda.destroy()



    def demanda(self, periodos):    
        self.newwindow=Toplevel()   
        
        for i in range(periodos):
        

            self.periodon=Label(self.newwindow, width=15, text=f"periodo {i+1}", font=20)
            self.periodon.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        for i in range(periodos):
            self.demanda=Entry(self.newwindow, width=15)
            self.demanda.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


        self.borrar=Button(self.newwindow, text="borrar todo", font=25, width=20,command=self.borra)
        self.borrar.grid(row=1+periodos,column=1, pady=15, padx=20)

        

    def createWidgets(self):
        numeroPeriodos=IntVar()

        self.pastPeriods=Label(self, text="Cantidad de entry:", font=30)
        self.pastPeriods.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=15,padx=20)

        self.numberPeriods=Entry(self, textvariable=numeroPeriodos)
        self.numberPeriods.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=15)

        self.continuePeriod=Button(self, text="Continuar", font=25, width=20, command=lambda:self.demanda(numeroPeriodos.get()))
        self.continuePeriod.grid(row=1,column=0, pady=15)

principalRoot=Tk()

app=principalWindow(principalRoot)

app.mainloop()
```

les agradezco
<3

Answer (score 1):

En cada iteración de los *bucles for* estás asignando un nuevo valor a las variables `self.periodon` y `self.demanda`. Al finalizar los bucles, estas variables hacen referencia al último *widget*.

Deberías utilizar listas. En el método `__init__` inicializa esas dos variables como listas vacías:

```py
self.periodon = []
self.demanda = []
```

Dentro del método `demanda`, añade el `Label` y el `Entry` creados en cada iteración a su correspondiente lista:

```py
for i in range(periodos):
    label = Label(self.newwindow, width=15, text=f"periodo {i+1}", font=20)
    label.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.periodon.append(label)

for i in range(periodos):
    entry = Entry(self.newwindow, width=15)
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.demanda.append(entry)
```

Finalmente, en el método `borra` itera sobre estas listas para *destruir* todos los elementos:

```py
for i in self.periodon:
    i.destroy()

for i in self.demanda:
    i.destroy()

self.periodon = []
self.demanda = []
```